# What does this segment of code check?

Tags: java, arrays

Can anyone tell me what the following code does? More specifically the (!duplicate) part. What exactly is the if statement checking?

```
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                boolean duplicate = false;
                    for (int x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {
                        if (integer[x] == list[i]) {
                            duplicate = true;
            //If integer is new, duplicate = false, if it's repeated in 
            //list, duplicate = true
        }
     }
        if (!duplicate) {
                integer[value++] = list[i];
        }
```

Comment: Need more context for better explanation. From this much, `duplicate` seems like a boolean variable. When it is false, it increments the value of `integer` array at index `value` with the value from `list[i]`.

Comment: @clinomaniac added more of the code. Hoping this helps

Comment: Don't tag spam, unless you want to attract negative attention.

Comment: Google *java logical operator tutorial*.

Comment: Are you asking what `!` means? What is your specific question?

Comment: Please provide valid Java code. For example `list, duplicate = true` does not make sense.

Comment: The first part is an inefficient way to determine if any value in an array named `list` is equal to any other value in the array. If one is found, the value in an array named `integer` at the index numbered `value` is set to the last value in the array named `list`, after which the number `value` is incremented by one. All these variables are very misleadingly named. The ultimate effect depends entirely on how those variables are used by other code -- out of context, this code isn't meaningful at all.

Comment: Actually, I'm not even confident of that, since the braces are unmatched and the indentation is misleading. It's not clear which blocks belong together.

Comment: This question is sad. If you read the block of code right above the original two lines you posted, it's clear that `bool duplicate = false;` means it's checking for duplicates, and therefore if it's set to true a duplicate was found. With that information, it's clear (reading the `if` in plain English): "it's checking if (something aboiut duplicate), and duplicate is a bool, so it's almost like it's checking if it's a duplicate but not quite.... if it's not checking a bool for true, what could it possibly be checking for instead of true?"

Comment: Especially when you consider the text in the two line comment immediately above the `if(!duplicate)` line.

Answer (score 0):

The example code you provided will do nothing since it is riddled with errors. I don't know where you got this code but it needs to be rethought. The original intent of the code is actually quite obvious, it is to create a new Integer Array which would contain all the ***distinct*** and ***unique*** integer values (no duplicates) contained within the supplied Integer Array named **list** which may or may not happen to contain duplicate values - a duplicate value is ignored and it's only the first instance of that duplicate that would be applied to the new Array along with any value within the 'list' Array that does not have a duplicate and is therefore deemed unique.

The boolean **duplicate** variable is simply used as a flag during the outer **for** loop to indicate that a duplicate value has been found within the 'list' Array during iteration by the inner **for** loop. When the inner **for** loop has finished the state of this flag is checked and if found to be **false** the value is added to the 'integer' Array. It would be a little more effective if the inner **for** loop was exited (with the **break** statement) as soon as it was established that the value currently being process is indeed a duplicate and the **duplicate** variable is set to boolean **true** since further processing of the initial integer value is no longer required and processing of the outer **for** loop can continue.

The code intent shown in your example is one way to do this sort of thing (there are several ways, just Google: "*remove duplicates from integer array with Java*")

Since you're dealing with Arrays they must be properly declared and initialized with the length required for the elements to be held for that Array, for example:

```
int[] integer = new int[12];
```

Generally, for this particular task (and many others), a lot of **new** programmers will declare and initialize the new Array (**integer** per se) to the very same length as the original Array they are inspecting for duplicates (or working against), for example:

```
int[] integer = int[list.length];
```

This is actually the wrong way to do this sort of thing since there could potentially be a lot of elements within the new Array that could contain 0 if duplicates were encountered. For every duplicate value encountered within the **list** Array, the **integer** Array would contain **1** less element but because the **integer** Array was initialized to the same length as the original **list** Array the element you think would not exist actually will exist and it would contain **0** since **int**'s default to 0 (be it a single Integer variable or elements within an Integer Array). Doing this is fine if your are prepared to deal with that situation during the progression of your code or, there actually were no duplicate values contained within the **list** Array to begin with for which there can be no certainty of in most cases. This is why most programmers tend to stay from Array when carrying out this particular type of task and use other Classes and or Methods instead.

To demonstrate the above scenario enter the following code into the **main()** method of a new Java Application project and run it:

```
    // Our Hard Coded Integer 'list' Array.
    int[] list = {1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 6, 7, 
                  2, 9, 5, 8, 0, 0, 1, 5, 8, 2};
    // Declare & initialize the 'integer' Array
    int[] integer = new int[list.length]; // Premature initialization
    boolean duplicate;
    idxCnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        duplicate = false;
        for (int x = (i + 1); x < list.length; x++) {
            if (list[i] == list[x]) {
                duplicate = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!duplicate) {
            integer[idxCnt] = list[i];
            idxCnt++;
       }        
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integer));
```

The console window will display:

```
[4, 3, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 5, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

By looking at the contents of the 'list' Array we can already see that there are 10 distinct numbers even though there are 20 elements, therefore there are obviously 10 duplicate values as well. Notice in the console display that only the first instance and unique values from the 'list' Array were indeed placed into the 'integer' array but at the end of the 'integer' Array there are 10 zeros (0) which simply are not needed. This is because the 'integer' Array was declared and initialized to be the same length as the 'list' Array which as we already know contains 20 elements.

**Note:** You may also have noticed that the code above shows a working version of the intent you displayed in your post.

In my opinion, when you are to fill an Array be sure to declare and initialize that Array to the exact length required. In order to do that in this case you need to iterate through the 'list' Array first so as to determine how many duplicate values actually exist and this is one way you can do that (sticking to the already established raw coding format):

```
    // Our Hard Coded Integer 'list' Array.
    int[] list = {1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 6, 7, 
                  2, 9, 5, 8, 0, 0, 1, 5, 8, 2};
    int idxCnt = 0;  // To eventually hold the number of duplicates.

    // Find out how many duplicates there are within
    // the 'list' int Array.
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (int x = (i + 1); x < list.length; x++) {
            if (list[i] == list[x]) { 
                idxCnt++; 
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("There are " + idxCnt + " duplicate values "
                     + "contained within the 'list' Array of\n" 
                     + list.length + " elements. We only "
                     + "need " + (list.length - idxCnt) + " elements "
                     + "for our 'integer' Array.");
```

If you were to run the above example code you would see in your Console window something like this:

```
There are 10 duplicate values contained within the 'list' Array of
20 elements. We only need 10 elements for our 'integer' Array.
```

**20 elements - 10 duplicates = 10** elements required for placing distinct values into the 'integer' Array.

Now that we know how many elements will be required for our 'integer' Array we can initialize it as such:

```
int[] integer = new int[idxCnt];
```

When everything is put together the code would look something like this:

```
// Our Hard Coded Integer 'list' Array.
    int[] list = {1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 6, 7, 
                  2, 9, 5, 8, 0, 0, 1, 5, 8, 2};
    boolean duplicate;  // Flag to indicate duplicate encountered.
    int[] integer;      // Declare the 'integer' Array
    int idxCnt = 0;     // To eventually hold the number of duplicates.

    // Find out how many duplicates there are within
    // the 'list' int Array.
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (int x = i+1; x < list.length; x++) {
            if (list[i] == list[x]) { 
                idxCnt++; 
                break; // No need to continue inner loop
            }
        }
    }

    // Initialize the new 'integer' Array
    integer = new int[list.length - idxCnt];

    // Retrieve distinct values from 'list' Array
    // and place them into the 'integer' Array.
    idxCnt = 0;     // Used as Index Counter.
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        duplicate = false;
        for (int x = (i + 1); x < list.length; x++) {
            if (list[i] == list[x]) {
                duplicate = true;
                break; // No need to continue inner loop
            }
        }
        if (!duplicate) {
            // Deemed as not duplicate so add the value
            // to the 'integer' Array
            integer[idxCnt] = list[i];
            idxCnt++; // Increment the index for 'integer' Array.
       }        
    }

    // Sort the 'integer Array.
    Arrays.sort(integer); 

    // Display the 'integer' Array to Console Window
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integer));
```

When run the above cod will display within the console window:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Rather drawn out isn't it. This is why most programmers who have to deal with an array prefer to do something a little easier on the eyes like this instead:

**Using Java 8**:

```
    // Our Hard Coded Integer 'list' Array.
    int[] list = {1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 6, 7, 
                  2, 9, 5, 8, 0, 0, 1, 5, 8, 2};
    // Convert Array to ArrayList (List Object)
    List<Integer> lst = Arrays.stream(list).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    // Remove duplicates.
    lst = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(lst));
    // Sort the List
    Collections.sort(lst); // If you want the List sorted.
    // Display List in console.
    System.out.println(lst);
```

Better yet, just deal with a List object rather than an array altogether (below assumes that all integer values are already contained within a List object named **list**):

```
list = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(list)); // To remove duplicates
Collections.sort(list);                      // To sort the List.
System.out.println(list);                    // Display List to console
```

The console output will be identical to all the previously supplied code examples and it's basically done with a two lines of code:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(lst))` will definitely *not* sort the values -- it will produce a list in an undefined order. You probably want `TreeSet` there instead of `HashSet`.

Comment: No, I did not intend `TreeSet`. I intended exactly as I had written it: `lst = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(lst));` (using diamond reference) which **does** indeed sort the Integer List elements using **Java 8** (which I have now indicted within my answer).

Comment: Please provide a reference for that assertion, as it contradicts both my personal experience and [the authoritative documentation for HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), which says: "It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time." (It *will* remove duplicates, but that is not the same as sorting.)

Comment: My apologies @DanielPryden (and everyone else), it is true, HashSet will not sort larger integer values above a single digit however with Integer values from 0 to 9 as the examples above show, it has no problem doing so. As far as the "order remaining constant over time" is not really relevant since HashSet is only used the one time for its use against the List. Since HashSet has this sorting limitation it makes it hardly worth using for a sort mechanism. Editing answer. Above all, Thank you Daniel for your patience and opening my eyes a little wider.